# Using a page break in SAS based on line numbers

Tags: sas

I am working on a SAS program to generate PDF report. There is part where a table(grid) is involved with fixed number of rows and columns. I need to place this table in such a way that it comes entirely on one page without any break. 
Now this grids position keeps on varying at this page and flows to next page as 
there is other table at top whose number of rows keep changing and hence the lines occupied on report keeps changing and is not fixed no.
I need a suggestion how can I get the table differentiated and find whether that particular table fits perfectly in that  in that particular report, else I all have to do a page break and get the entire table in next report, Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ods pdf startpage=now` just before the fixed-size table, e.g.

```
option orientation=landscape;

ods _all_ close;
ods pdf file = "/folders/myfolders/test.pdf";

/*Print a table*/
proc print data = sashelp.cars(obs=100);
run;

ods pdf startpage = now;

/*Print another table starting on a new page*/
proc print data = sashelp.class;
run;

ods pdf close;
ods listing;
```

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for the answer,but i have tried this earlier, as i told you that that the fixed size table  table has to be on page 1 it page allows ,but since remaining space on page is dependent on the variable sized table above ,so if i use the  'ods pdf startpage = now' option it will direct entire table to page 2,even if it can be managed on page 1 as the above variable sized tables may be less in size on page.

Comment: Your comment is very hard to read. I suggest you post a picture showing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you saying that your fixed size table ends up on page 2 even if you print it before the other one? Please could you post an example of code that causes this?